# jquery using multiple setTimeouts

Tags: javascript, jquery, timeout

I am currently creating a site with some dynamic content, so that whenever a user hovers over a label, the label expands to show more information, then after a specific time the label will collapse again, unless the user hovers over the label again in which case the Timeout will reset. I have developed the code to do this for 1 label, but I would to develop it now to do it for multiple labels.

The problem I'm having though is that I am defining the variable for the timer globally so it can be used for both events, this won't work when I have multiple labels though.

I can't think how I can achieve this for multiple labels, does anyone have any idea how I can do this?

Here is my code so far...

```
    var timer;


    $('.label').mouseenter(function(){

        clearTimeout(timer);

        $('#' + this.id + ' div').slideDown('slow');

    });


    $('.label').mouseleave(function(){

        var temp = $('#' + this.id + ' div');

        timer = setTimeout(function() { 
            temp.stop().slideUp('slow');
        }, 2000);

    });
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can maintain an array of timers like

```
var timer = [];


$('.label').mouseenter(function(){

    clearTimeout(timer[$(this).index()]);

    $('#' + this.id + ' div').slideDown('slow');

});


$('.label').mouseleave(function(){

    var temp = $('#' + this.id + ' div');

    timer[$(this).index()] = setTimeout(function() { 
        temp.stop().slideUp('slow');
    }, 2000);

});
```

You can also achieve this with a more clear syntax using [`.hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) like

```
var timer = [];

$('.label').hover(function(){

    clearTimeout(timer[$(this).index()]);

    $('#' + this.id + ' div').slideDown('slow');

},function(){
    var temp = $('#' + this.id + ' div');

    timer[$(this).index()] = setTimeout(function() { 
        temp.stop().slideUp('slow');
    }, 2000);

});
```

Comment: That has worked a charm!!!! For some reason my brain seems to be having trouble working today. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 3):

Why dont you use `hover` :

```
$('.label').hover(function(){
  $('#' + this.id + ' div').slideDown('slow');
},
function(){
  $('#' + this.id + ' div').slideUp('slow');
})
```

This way, when labels are hovered upon, more info will show and when mouse leaves them, they will hide back again.

The first param to `hover` is for mouse enter while second for mouse leave.

**More Info:**

http://api.jquery.com/hover/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using global variable `timer` you can use jQuery's `.data()` method like this:

```
$('.label').hover(function(){
    clearTimeout($(this).data('hover_timeout'));
    $('#' + this.id + ' div').slideDown('slow');
},function(){
    var temp = $('#' + this.id + ' div');
    $(this).data('hover_timeout', setTimeout(function() { 
        temp.stop().slideUp('slow');
    }, 2000));
});
```

[jQuery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) documentation